# how to control google's search engine result page of a website

Tags: web-development, google-search, seo, search-results

lately google search seem to have interesting new result snippets and I wonder how they generate them.

More specifically one got my attention, see the links "15 minutes - 5 minutes - Timer - E.ggTimer.com" in the screenshot. How can I generate these links?[image]

Answer (score 2):

That's some navigation they extracted from the page to use as [rich snippets](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/topic.py?topic=21997).
One of them is actually a bit "wrong." If you hover over the "Timer - E.ggTimer.com" item, you'll see it's actually a link to set a 30min timer. This suggests to me these were automatically generated, but you'll find information at the previous link for gaining some control over them.

Comment: Actaully, those are sitelinks, not Rich Snippets: http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=47334